# azure devops , checkout only the runner branch in CI

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

how can I do it , I added this one but I not sure if is right:

```
steps:
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 1
  clean: true
```

Comment: Are you sure you aren't just looking for it to trigger on only a specific branch instead using a [trigger filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/trigger?view=azure-pipelines#examples-1)?

Comment: Are the answers helpful to you? Please check the answer, if it is correct, please check it as a correct one. And if you have any question,we are willing to help you

Answer (score 0):

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: MyRepo
    type: git
    name: Myrepo
    ref: master

steps:
- checkout: MyRepo
```

This should work

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I will describe my question differently
I want to checkout only from the branch that runs the ci

Comment: You could pass this
$(Build.SourceBranch) instead of master

Comment: steps:
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 1
  clean: true



so that is not right for my demand ?